# How to run my shell script from windows Webpage?

Tags: windows, shell, remote-access, unix

I want to execute some batch jobs from my unix box thro shell scripts.

Scenario:

I have some shell scripts in my unix box, want to run those scripts thro my windows webpage. This is to achieve by click on a button from the webpage.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The messy way:

Set up a web server on the unix box, use whatever programming language you fancy (say, PHP, Python, Perl) to generate a suitable web page, and make it do a system call to your script when it sees a postback. A very dumbed-down example in PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['do_it'])) {
        $result = `my_super_shell_script.sh`;
    }
?>
<html>
<head><title>Run a script</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <button type="submit" name="do_it" value="1">Do It!</button>
    </form>
    <pre>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This, however, is full of problems. Most of all security: Anyone who can send a post request to your page can trigger the script, which is not usually what you want. You'll have to take extra measures to make sure nobody can access the page without prior authorization.

### The nice solution:

Just use ssh. It doesn't give you a web site, but using PuTTY (or any other ssh client), you can simply log into the Unix box without exposing it to the whole world.

Comment: It seems to be tedious to run a script from windows. i used putty to run the script for now.